# Send NSData to WCF Service using JSON

Tags: iphone, json, wcf, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to upload a file from iPhone to the Web Site using WCF Service. The WCF service has a lot of methods that I can call from the iPhone successfuly except this one.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
   UriTemplate = "UploadFileBinary")]
UploadFileResponse jsonUploadFile(UploadFileRequest request);
```

UploadFileRequest contains byte[] and string for FileBinaryData and FileName respectively.

The problem is that I have the file data as NSData object and do not know how to convert it to JSON compatible format. I tried some suggestions but none worked for me.

Comment: Hey why dont you use NSInputStream to upload a file if you are tying to upload. It has a method - (void)setHTTPBodyStream:(NSInputStream *)inputStream which will really help you if you want to upload a file. By the way, you can also append the body to NSMutableUrlRequest body using method like - (void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data and then passing the data for your file.

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up converting the WCF byte[] to string and encode/decode my byte[] as base64 string. I did not know about NSInputStream but I may look into that later in the next update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to change the WCF data contract and add a data member of type string.

on the iPhone side encode NSData as base64 string
on the WCF side decode the string and get the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a JSON string represented by your data?  If so...

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
```

Or are you looking for real NSObjects that JSON represents once parsed?  That's easy, too...

```
NSError *error;
id parse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for something like this
{"FileName" : "Image1.png", "FileData" : ??????}